# Automorphism group of quadric bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, automorphism-group

I am interested in smooth quadric bundles $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$. Where $X$ is a smooth complex projective $3$-fold and all the fibres are smooth so that $f^{-1}(p) \cong \mathbb{CP}^{1} \times \mathbb{CP}^{1}$.

According to Beauville, for each such quadric bundle, there is a rank $4$-bundle E and a line bundle $L$ and a section $s \in H^{0}(S^{2}E^* \otimes L)$, such that $X = \{s=0\} \subset \mathbb{P}(E)$. By Grothendieck, and since tensoring by a line bundle doesn't change the projectivisation, without loss of generality we may write $E = \mathcal{O}(n_{1}) \oplus \mathcal{O}(n_{2}) \oplus \mathcal{O}(n_{3}) \oplus \mathcal{O}$  and $L = \mathcal{O}(m)$.

**Question**: Is there a way to compute the automorphism group of $X$ from the data $\{ n_{i},m,s \}$? b. Is there a convenient criteria to know when $X$ is toric?

Edit: Is it possible to say anything about group the subgroup $Aut_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}(X) \subset Aut(X)$ preserving fibers?

Comment: I believe that the automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}(E)$ can be computed following the ideas from Maruyama https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kjm/1250523688 And then use it to compute the automorphism group of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I agree it is possible to compute the automorphism groups of $\mathbb{P}(E)$. How to use this to compute the automorphism group of $X$?

Comment: The embedding defines a homomorphism of automorphism groups. If it is a monomorphism then $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is the stabilizer of $s$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{P}(E))$

Comment: Thanks again. Do you have a reference for the fact that the embedding defines a homomorphism of automorphism groups?, it looks interesting.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake but this way we can analyse only $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(X)$, the automorphisms that preserve $f$.

Following Beauville's theorem you see that the embedding is realized by some linear system relatively ample over $\mathbb{P}^1$. Then the action of $\operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(X)$ on this linear system leads to the homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, +1, even to understand $Aut_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}(X)$ would be very useful for me. I think that I can more or less see that $X$ is realised by a linear system relatively ample over $\mathbb{P}^{1}$. Since it is the restriction of the square of the tautological bundle on $\mathbb{P}(E)$ i.e. $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(2)$, which is clearly relatively ample. I am struggling to see how this leads to a homomorphism, please could you point me to a reference?